# How do I read a docx file from Google Cloud Storage into a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, blob, docx

I'm seeking help in completing a basic task on Google Cloud Platform.  Specifically, I'm looking to read into my Jupyter Notebook a docx file that lives in a bucket on my google cloud storage account.  I intend to perform this task in bulk, from a Vertex AI workbench instance, so I'm looking for Python code that can be scaled and with efficiency.  Not a quick work-a-round.

Here's what I have (blob):

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = "sample_bucket"
file_name = "Folder/sample_msword_document.docx"
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.get_blob(file_name)
content = blob.download_as_string()
```

From here, I want to read in the text of the msword (docx) file so to do text analysis.

However, there’s clearly an extra line of code needed in order for the contents of my blob to be converted into readable text.

For instance, if I print the file as a string (as is), it is in a coding format (xml?) that is unreadable.

'PK\x##\x##\x##\x##\x##\x##\x##\x##\x##\x##!\x##J~3\x##\x##\x##\t\x##\x##\x##\x##\x##\x##[Content_Types].xml ...'

So ultimately, what additional line of code do I need to convert this unreadable string into readable text?

Preferably, I would like to keep it a word doc (docx) so to utilize the ***docx*** Python package.  But converting contents straight to a text variable is a reasonable alternative for my purposes.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "Now what?" is not really an actionable question.  You will need to describe in more detail what you're trying to accomplish (be specific) using the inputs available, what you tried, and what's not working the way you expect.  We can't solve generalized problems not knowing what your destination is or what your problem is really about.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks!  I edited the question to make it as specific as possible.

Comment: Also, John Hanley.  Yes.  The docx python package is what I typically use reading in msword documents from local directories.  However, pulling data from Google cloud storage requires me to set up a client and read in contents as a “blob”.  My struggle is that as a “blob” I can’t apply the docx package (you provided).  So there must be someway to get the “blob” contents into readable text and/or into a format that is readable by docx python package.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!  I found the missing piece to my code.  Turns out I was 90% of the way there.

Instead of downloading the file as a string ("blob.download_as_string"), I needed to download the file and write it to my working directory ("blob.download_as_file") using the Python command **open()**.  Once read in as docx file on my working directory, I then was able to utilize Python's docx package (as shared by John Hanley).

Here's the missing code needed:

```
import os
import docx

filepath=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'sample_msword_document.docx')  #find working directory

with open(filepath,'wb') as f:
          blob.download_to_file(f)  #download file to working directory
f.close()

doc = docx.Document(filepath)  #read downloaded file back in using docx package
```

So, altogether, the final script should look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage
import os
import docx

client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = "sample_bucket"
file_name = "Folder/sample_msword_document.docx"
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.get_blob(file_name)

filepath=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'sample_msword_document.docx')

with open(filepath,'wb') as f:
          blob.download_to_file(f)
f.close()

doc = docx.Document(filepath)
```

The variable **doc** is the specific result I was looking for when I asked my question.  Hence, my question is fully answered.

I do invite further responses related to more efficient ways to accomplish the task.  I plan to process docx files in bulk, so efficiency is a very important factor.